# Increasing max_input_vars = 6000 on Bitnami Multisite Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, multisite

We are using Bitnami Multisite stack-

I need some help  in increasing `max_input_vars = 6000` 
Already made changes on `php.ini` file to reflect it.

However, it is not changing - I also restarted Apache and php-fpm services.

Still No Luck - Still `max_input_vars = 1000`.

We are hosting on Azure - Any help would be appreciated

is there any way we can .user.ini file on Bitnami Multisite Stack >?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Google Console Cloud
2. Compute Engine
3. VM instances
4. SHH Open in browser
5. sudo chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
6. sudo -i
7. nano /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
8. Control +w = search “max_input_vars” enter and change check line start without “;”
9. Control + x  yes after enter
10. sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
11. php -i | grep max_input_vars

Comment: But where is this value need to be set?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Please note that the max_input_vars line is commented by default and it's value (if not defined) is 1000. You need to define it this way

```
max_input_vars = 6000
```

and restart all the service

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

I checked that PHP returns that value later

```
$ php -i | grep max_input_vars
max_input_vars => 6000 => 6000
```

and Apache and PHP-FPM are also using that value

[image]